# using string split method to split prompt values

Tags: split, prompt

I am trying to split my prompt values so that each word appears on a different line, but my code makes it so that the words are split by commas instead of to each line like I want it to. Thank you so much for helping!

```
<p div id="a"></div></p>

<script>

window.onload=function() {
var x=prompt("Enter Terms", "Terms")
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=x.split(" ");
      for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
document.write(a[i]);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), *joins all elements of an `array` into a `string` using specified `argument`*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = prompt("Enter Terms", "Terms");
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = x.split(" ").join('<br/>');
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```